# single value computation

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, algorithms

I was solving a coding problem where given a bunch of numbers, i need to compute step difference till i'm left with only one number.
For example numbers are 3, 5, 2, 6, 7 such that my result is computed as (3-5)-(5-2)-(2-6)-(6-7) till i'm left with only one number.

```
3   5   2   6   7
 -2   3  -4  -1
   -5   7  -3
     -12  10
       -22 <----answer
```

I applied an iterative approach which gives my result in quadratic time so i want to know is there any formula available through which i can compute such difference in much faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are given, I think that the answer is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}a_i.$$

For 5 numbers $a,b,c,d,e$, one has
$$a,b,c,d,e$$
$$a-b,b-c,c-d,d-e$$
$$a-2b+c,b-2c+d,c-2d+e$$
$$a-3b+3c-d,b-3c+3d-e$$
$$a-4b+6c-4d+e$$

This can be written as $$\binom{4}{0}a-\binom{4}{1}b+\binom{4}{2}c-\binom{4}{3}d+\binom{4}{4}e.$$

Comment: thank you so much @mathlove you are awesome :)

Comment: @gds: You are welcome. Glad to help you.